# if i set alarm manager to specific time to run at , must check after boot

Tags: android, service, alarmmanager

if i set alarm manager to specific time to run at.
must check after boot android and create a service ?

I want to check if he done an action in past 24 Hours , if not show alarm and so on every day .

I want to understand 
when we add an alarm to a specific time , android put the alarms in something like table and check with himself if the time is reached and execute ?
OR
we must check if the time reached with ourselves with service ?

Comment: You'll need to write this again more clearly I think...

Comment: So, you want a boot resistant Repeating daily alarm, right? Here you'll find the official documentation AND a downloadable example: https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html

Comment: @AssafGamliel & Der Golem
I want to understand when we add an alarm to a specific time , android put the alarms in something like table and check with himself if the time is reached and execute ? OR we must check if the time reached with ourselves with service ?

Comment: @user1475257 Android will do it for you, I don't think it works with a table, for batching alarms together I'd use something else, but it seems that this is besides the point for your questions. So, yes, Android takes care of it for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find it's more efficiency to use Message Queuing System like RabbitMQ, or Database like FireBase to manage this.